# Persistent Message Delivery Mode when a Queue subscribes to a Topic

Tags: solace

I have a queue subscribing from a topic.  My MQTT client publishes messages to the topic. My Java program consumes messages from the queue using JCSMP API.  However, I notice that the delivery mode of the messages received by my Java program from the Queue is DIRECT or sometimes NON-PERSISTENT.  So, does this mean my messages will not be spooled to SAN?  Is it possible for me to set topic subscription for my queue so that all messages received from the topic and stored in this queue will be persistent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When the Solace appliance receives a message that was published to a topic that matches a topic subscription set on a queue, the message will be delivered to the queue and spooled. If this message is originally set with a DIRECT delivery mode, the delivery mode will be promoted to NON-PERSISTENT. NON-PERSISTENT messages are treated as a Guaranteed Message and will be spooled.

If you are receiving a NON-PERSISTENT message, the message was properly spooled on the queue.

When the Solace appliance receives a message that was published to a topic that matches a topic subscription applied directly on a client, they message will not be spooled and will be delivered directly to the client without being queued. If this message is originally published with a NON-PERSISTENT or PERSISTENT delivery mode, it will be demoted and received by the client as DIRECT.

If you are receiving messages with a delivery mode of DIRECT, verify that the client is not directly subscribed to the topic. The topic should be applied on the queue that the client is bound to instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.